# how to see the file which would be committed

Tags: git, git-patch, git-apply

I have modified a file (or some files) in my directory, and I've used `git add` to stage some of the changes lines from the file, but not all the changed line.

I can use `git diff --staged my-file` to see the diff of what's changed.  `git diff --staged my-file` ignores lines which were changed but not staged.   Here is an example of the output of `git diff --staged my-file`

```
diff --git a/ens/cours/ens_cours_JN.csv b/ens/cours/ens_cours_JN.csv
index dcea574..ff33469 100644
--- a/ens/cours/ens_cours_JN.csv
+++ b/ens/cours/ens_cours_JN.csv
@@ -24,6 +24,7 @@ SCALIN_E;EPITA;préparation pédagogique;JN;ING1;2020-05-13;;False;True;PT4H;;
 SCALIN_E;EPITA;préparation pédagogique;JN;ING1;2020-05-20;;False;True;PT4H;;
 SCALIN_E;EPITA;préparation pédagogique;JN;ING1;2020-05-27;;False;True;PT4H;;
 SCALIN_E;EPITA;préparation pédagogique;JN;ING1;2020-06-03;;False;True;PT4H;;
+SCALIN_E;EPITA;préparation pédagogique;JN;ING1;2020-06-03;;False;True;PT4H;;commit this line
 THLR;EPITA;préparation pédagogique;JN;ING1;2020-07-20;;False;True;PT8H;;Recording TDs
 THLR;EPITA;préparation pédagogique;JN;ING1;2020-07-21;;False;True;PT8H;;Recording TDs
 THLR;EPITA;préparation pédagogique;JN;ING1;2020-07-22;;False;True;PT8H;;Recording TDs
```

Question:  How can I generate the text of the file which *would be* committed?    I'd like a check-in hook to eventually process that file before allowing the commit.

I suspect there is some simple incantation using `git apply`.  However, a simple use of `git apply` produces the following diagnostic messages.

```
jnewton@Marcello cours % git diff --staged > ens_cours_JN.csv.patch
git diff --staged > ens_cours_JN.csv.patch
jnewton@Marcello cours % git apply ens_cours_JN.csv.patch
git apply ens_cours_JN.csv.patch
error: patch failed: ens/cours/ens_cours_JN.csv:24
error: ens/cours/ens_cours_JN.csv: patch does not apply
```

I have a solution that seems far too complicated.

1. generate the .patch file with `git diff --staged > my-file.patch`
2. save the original with `cp my-file my-file.save`
3. stash the changes with `git stash save my-file`
4. apply the patch with `git apply my-file.patch`
5. saved the desired result with `cp my-file my-file.to-commit`
6. restore the file to the pre-add state with `mv my-file.save my-file`
7. restore the fiel to the post-add state with `git stash apply`

Now, `my file.to-commit` is a copy of the fill which would be committed.
Is this really the correct way to do this?  It seems like I'm doing too much work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `:[<n>:]<path>` construct to access to corresponding staged blob, and just do

```
git show :my-file
```

As described [here](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) :

> `:[<n>:]<path>, e.g. :0:README, :README`
> *A colon, optionally followed by a stage number (0 to 3) and a colon, followed by a path, names a blob object in the index at the given path. A missing stage number (and the colon that follows it) names a stage 0 entry. During a merge, stage 1 is the common ancestor, stage 2 is the target branch’s version (typically the current branch), and stage 3 is the version from the branch which is being merged.*

So `git show :0:path/to/file` or the shorter `git show :path/to/file` outputs the full staged version of the file.

Answer (score 2):

For individual files, you can use [`git checkout-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout-index) :

```
# will overwrite 'that/file.txt' in place with the indexed version :
git checkout-index -- that/file.txt

# will create '/tmp/that/file.txt' :
git checkout-index --prefix=/tmp/ -- that/file.txt
```

Or you can mention explicitly the target [`--work-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt---work-treeltpathgt) and [`--git-dir`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt---git-dirltpathgt) (options to `git` itself, not to its subcommand), and use `git checkout` :

```
git --git-dir=.git/ --work-tree=/tmp/myindex/ checkout -- .
```

---

Also worth mentioning :

- `git stash -k` will store your unstaged changes in a stash, preserve the index as it is and restore the content on disk to the indexed content
  you can then use `git stash apply` or `git stash pop` to get your unstaged changes back
- `git checkout -- some/path` will get the version from the *index* on disk (it will overwrite your local changes, use `git stash -k` or some other way to checkout your files if that's a problem)